# How I can run 'cpan' inside emacs?

Tags: perl, emacs

I like to know how I can run cpan to install modules using emacs? I often do that on command line now.

Update: I had asked this because I get the message "warning: extra args ignored after '-e'"
when I use M-x shell to run it. I still need help.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried **M-x shell**?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no tight integration of CPAN into Emacs, so going through `shell` will probably be your best bet. If you use `w3m-el`, you may also find this useful:

```
(add-to-list 'w3m-search-engine-alist '("cpan" "http://search.cpan.org/search?query=%s&n=100"))
```

From within any *w3m* buffer, I use this and a few keystrokes (`C-u S RET cpan RET <search-term>`) to find CPAN modules.

Comment: +1 for this.  didn't know about `w3m-search-engine` Too used to `webjump` I guess.

Answer (score 3):

```
M-!
```

aka

```
M-x shell-command
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same thing and google found this workaround (from http://www.mail-archive.com/help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org/msg04015.html) :

```
cmd /c "foo.bat arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

This seems like an awkward hack, but it works.

Comment: How do you apply this in emacs?

Comment: After reading your question more thoroughly this may not apply.

Using M-x eshell I see:
   SomeCommand.bat abc
     warning: extra args ignored after 'SomeCommand.bat'
   cmd /c "SomeCommand.bat abc"
     expected output

Using M-x shell I see:
   SomeCommand.bat abc
     expected output

You said you are using M-x shell and I don't see the same issue you do, so maybe the workaround does not apply.